# How do I override applicationIdSuffix for a particular build variant?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have the following in my app.gradle:

```
flavorDimensions 'app', 'type'
productFlavors {
    AppA {
        dimension 'app'
        applicationIdSuffix '.appa'
    }
    AppB {
        dimension 'app'
        applicationIdSuffix '.appb'
    }
    TypeA {
        dimension 'type'
        applicationIdSuffix '.typea'
    }
    TypeB {
        dimension 'type'
        applicationIdSuffix '.typeb'
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    println("Flavor name: " + variant.flavorName.toLowerCase())
    if (variant.flavorName.toLowerCase() == "appatypea") {
        println("Detected legacy app.")
        //variant.productFlavors[0].applicationIdSuffix = ""
        variant.mergedFlavor.setApplicationId("com.example.special")
    }
}
```

If I try to build an app with flavors AppA and TypeA though, it still attaches the applicationIdPrefixes. So I get applicationId `com.example.special.appa.typea`.

How do I get Gradle to disregard the applicationIdSuffix in this one case?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @4ndro1d it's been awhile! I don't seem to have changed the code though, so I would double-check that this approach doesn't work in Android, just in case it does.